# JVM optimisation of hashCode() on List

Tags: java, list, optimization, hash, jvm

Imagine a simple case:

```
class B{
    public final String text;
    public B(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }
}

class A {
    private List<B> bs = new ArrayList<B>;

    public B getB(String text){
        for(B b :bs){
           if(b.text.equals(text)){
               return b;
           }
        }
        return null;
    }

    [getter/setter]
}
```

Imagine that for each instance of A, the `List<B>` is **large** and we need to call `getB(String)` **often**. However assume that it is also possible for the list to change (add/remove element, or even  being reassigned).

At this stage, the average complexity for getB(String) is O(n). In order to improved that I was wondering if we could use some clever caching.

Imagine we cache the `List<B>` in a `Map<String, B>` where the key is `B.text`. That would improve the performance but it won't work if the list is changed (new element or deleted element) or reassigned  (`A.bs` points to a new reference).

To go around that I thought that, along with the `Map<String, B>`, we could store a hash of the list `bs`. When we call `getB(String)` method, we compute the hash of the list `bs`. If the hash hasn't changed, we fetch the result from the map, if it has we reload the map.

The problem is that computing the hash for a `java.util.List` goes through all the element of the list and computes their hash, which is at least O(n).

**Question**

What I'd like to know is whether the JVM will be faster at computing the hash for the List than going through my loop in the `getB(String)` method. May be that depends on the implementation of hash for `B`. If so what kind of things could work? In a nutshell, I'd like to know whether this is stupid or could bring some performance improvement.

Comment: Just mutate the Map directly (instead of mutating the List and caching it in a Map)

Comment: This is just a simple example to illustrate a problem. Imagine that you are working with an existing application that already expects a List. Changing the List to a Map is not an option because you don't want to change the rest of the application too much

Comment: You can't theoretically recalculate the hash code after a random list change without going through all the elements again.

Comment: @phoenix7360 The existing application is badly designed then. It should either expect an `Iterable` or a `Collection` so you can pass it the map's `valueSet()`. I don't think it's very reasonable to want to have read-write O(1) access using two sets of keys, not without a custom collection designed to support that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You could maybe kinda sorta do this if you didn't care about the order of the items in the hash, seeing as XOR is commutative. Whenever an item is inserted or deleted, set the hash to the previous value ^ hash of the item being changed. (This would increase the chance of collisions a fair bit, depending on the input data.) That said, I don't think the OP is really asking about using the List itself as a hash key, the question is confusingly phrased.

Comment: @millimoose But that would imply you are using XOR (or any other *linear* function) to combine hashcodes; this would be a very poor practice, and precisely *due* to its linearity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without actually explaining why, you seem for some reason to believe that it is essential to keep the list structure as well. The only reasonable reason for this is that you need the order of the collection to be kept consistent. If you switch to a "plain" map, the order of the values is no longer constant, e.g. kept in the order in which you add the items to the map.

If you need both to keep the order (list behaviour) *and* access individual items using a key, you can use a `LinkedHashMap`, which essentially joins the behaviour of a `LinkedList` and a `HashMap`. Even if `LinkedHashMap.values()` returns a collection and not a list, the list behaviour is guaranteed within the collection.

Another issue with your question is, that you cannot use the list's hash code to safely determine changes. If the hash code has changed, you are indeed sure that the list has changed as well. If two hash codes are identical, you can still not be sure that the lists are actually identical. E.g. if the hash code implementation is based on strings, the hash codes for "1a" and "2B" are identical.

Comment: Ok this is quite interesting. The reason I have been insisting on a list is because I am working with a large application that has already been written this way. I was trying to see whether there was a light weight solution that wouldn't involved refactoring a lot of existing code. However it there is no such solution, yes switching for a better data structure seems appropriate. I quite like your LinkedHashMap. I probably should mention that A and B are JPA entities. Not sure how it impacts the data structure choice.

Comment: From all these discussions I take that there is no easy way to improve the performance without redesigning the model. If I were to do that, I would persist the `B` in a Map and return `Collection` of `B` from `A` using `values`.

Answer (score 1):

> If so what kind of things could work?

Simply put: don't let anything else mutate your list without you knowing about it. I suspect you currently have something like:

```
public List<String> getAllBs() {
    return bs;
}
```

... and a similar setter. If you stop doing that, and instead just have appropriate mutation methods, then you can make sure that your code is the *only* code to mutate the list... which means you can either remember that your map is "dirty" or just mutate the map at the same time that you mutate the list.

Comment: Yes I guess that would work. Out of interest do you have any comment on the computation of the hash?

Comment: @phoenix7360: No, I wouldn't expect the hash to be computed any faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own class `IndexedBArrayList` which extends `ArrayList<B>`.

Then you add this functionality to it:

- A `private HashMap<String, B> index`
- All mutator methods of ArrayList are overridden to keep this index hash map updated in addition to calling the corresponding super-method.
- A new `public B getByString(String)` method which uses the hash map

Answer (score 0):

From your description it does not seem that you need a `List<B>`.
Replace the `List` with a `HashMap`. If you need to search for `B`s the best data structure is the hashmap and not the list.

Comment: This is simple example to illustrate my question. Assume that by business requirement this has to be a List

Comment: @phonenix7360: `Assume that by business requirement this has to be a List` Business requirements do not specify data structures. Developers use the best data-structure available for the implementation of the business requirements

Comment: OK, imagine that the application is already using a list and your business requirement is to improve this piece of code without changing the rest of the application using this class. Imagine that you are using a JPA entity and you want to persist a List rather than a map.

Comment: @phoenix7360: Then why not modify the JPA mappings to persist a map instead of a list?

Comment: There could be other reasons why one MUST use an array list in this case, for example because other components expect an ArrayList and it would be too expensive to change these (sure, reeks of code smell, but reality isn't perfect).

Comment: @Philipp:This is a valid argument.But how is this clear from the OP? The OP only asks to get better search performance from a list.

Comment: @phoenix7360 It's more common for JPA to handle `Set`s and I don't think there's a reason why most of your one-to-many mappings can't just be `Collection`s. Persisting `List`s only makes sense if you need the database layer to keep track of the relative order of items as entered by the user, which isn't always necessary.

Comment: Yes as Phillip said, the main reason for not changing the list is that a large amount of code is expecting a list. Of course if there is no solution without refactoring going for a map rather than a List seems a good idea

Comment: @phoenix7360 Expecting a `List` when you need a `Collection` is a massive design smell, albeit a common form of laziness.

Comment: Yeah I guess that my example should probably be designed with a `Collection`. In my actual problem, one of the class was actually using a `Set` (another example was using a `List` because the element needed to be ordered).